# How to disable a HTML element from being shown while screen share

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a way to block a HTML element from showing up in screen share?
The current solution I have is to make a toggle that manually hides any element before user shares their screen. I was wondering if we do it dynamically with JavaScript.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't know that the screen is being shared, so no.

Comment: why not just create a different view where you hide certain elements instead? or log in with a different user with limitations before your call?

Comment: I doubt there's even a universal standard that defines whether a screen is being shared in any way, let alone a standard browser API which exposes that information to JavaScript.

Answer (score -4):

Identify the HTML element you want to hide during screen sharing. Let's say it has an ID of "elementToHide".

Use JavaScript to dynamically hide this element when the user initiates a screen share.

Here's a code example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Screen Share Element Hiding</title>
    <style>
        /* Some basic styling */
        #elementToHide {
            display: block; /* Or whatever your default display is */
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="elementToHide">
    <!-- Content you want to hide during screen share -->
    <p>This is the element you want to hide during screen share.</p>
</div>

<script>
    function hideElementDuringScreenShare() {
        var elementToHide = document.getElementById('elementToHide');
        if (elementToHide) {
            elementToHide.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }

    // Example trigger for initiating screen share
    // Replace this with your actual implementation
    // For instance, you might have a button that starts screen share
    // and calls hideElementDuringScreenShare() when clicked.
    document.getElementById('startScreenShareButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
        hideElementDuringScreenShare();
        // Add code to start screen share here
    });
</script>

<!-- Example button to start screen share -->
<button id="startScreenShareButton">Start Screen Share</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: good one, however, this would not work if screen is shared via a 3rd party app, for example microsoft teams

Comment: You assume the screen share is started from the web page, which it most likely wouldn't be.